# How to dynamically create a form inside container using reflection?

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, containers, methodinfo

I'm trying to create a generic library that is able to create one instance of a given Form. I'm using the WeifenLuo library.

In the main form, there is a dock container. If I create an instance directly in the method, it worked. However, when I call my generic method it shows the new Form outside the container.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // This works and put the new form inside the container
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            form.Show(mainFormDockPanel);
            // This just create the new form and open it outside the container
            //Forms.OpenForm<Form1>(this.mainFormDockPanel);
            Debug.WriteLine("Content: " + mainFormDockPanel.Contents.Count);
        }
```

Here is the generic function:

```
public static void OpenForm<T>(DockPanel dockPanel, T form = null, object obj = null, bool maximized = false) where T : class, new()
        {
            CreateMainForm();

            // Search for open forms
            foreach (DockContent frm in dockPanel).Contents)
            {
                // Verify if the content exists
                if (frm.GetType() == typeof(T) && obj == null)
                {
                    frm.Activate();
                    return;
                }
                // Check if the pressed button has a form
                if (obj != null && frm.GetType() == obj.GetType())
                {
                    frm.Activate();
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (form == null)
            {
                form = new T();
            }

            if (maximized)
                (form as DockContent).WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

            Type type = typeof(T);
            MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Show", new Type[] { typeof(IWin32Window) });
            methodInfo.Invoke(form, new object[] { dockPanel });

            
        }
```

Do you guys realize what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Forms.OpenForm<Form1, DockPanel>` doesn't match the signature of `OpenForm<T>`. Have you copied the wrong method?

Comment: Ups, my apologies @Steeeve. I just fix it. The right method I'm using is `Forms.OpenForm<Form1>`

Comment: Can't you just use `where T : Form, new()` instead of `where T : class, new()` and call the `Form.Show(IWin32Window)` method without reflection?

Comment: Hey @Steeeve, you're awesome! Thanks for your suggestion, It worked. I only changed the `where T : Form, new()` to `where T : DockPanel, new()`. The only doubt I'll keep is why that method didn't work using reflection? Anyways, thanks again.

Comment: Is Form1 derived from DockPanel and DockPanel from Form? Does either Form1 or DockPanel have a new Show(IWin32Window) method? If so, you get this method by using reflection, not the right one defined by the Form class. Try changing `Type type = typeof(T)` in `Type type = typeof(Form)`.